# Vaadin 7 add buttons into Accordion com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.Tab caption

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is it possible to add a buttons in Vaadin 7 to Accordion `com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.Tab` caption ?

Right now I can only add a String into Tab caption.

This is my current screen:

[image]

I need to add the same Edit/Remove icons(as I have for Live Chat and WMA)  near the General and Julia Group tab captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible.

You could create a server-side composition, which behaves like Accordion but then you could design the component so that you can add buttons to tab captions. You could start with something like this:

```
public class MyAccordion extends CustomComponent {

    public MyAccordion() {

        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(layout);
        // TODO layout should contain all tabs and tab captions
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create an [extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html#gwt.extension) by using GWT or Javascript and on the client-side modify DOM so that there a two buttons on tab captions.